# Identifying a 20 pin laptop chip that gets very hot within seconds

Tags: identification, surface-mount, microchip

I’ve been searching online to try and find out what this laptop chip does or any indication as to what would be a suitable replacement.

Currently, when power is put to the board, this gets to 90° within seconds so I’m pretty sure this is the reason my laptop won’t turn on.

[image: close up image]

[image: part shown on PCB]

Comment: What’s the package size?

Comment: I can't help you identify it, but you need to find out **why** the chip is getting so hot. Otherwise replacing it could end up with another very hot, dead chip if you have not cleared an underlying fault elsewhere. Can you track down any schematics for the laptop? Google "[laptop name] schematic" might throw something up.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help. I have tried to find a schematic or board view for either the laptop or the board part number but haven’t found one yet

Comment: Looks like a QFN-20 package to my untrained eye but beyond that no idea.

Comment: Please give more details and some more overview of what is around that chip. Seeing, what is around that chip could help giving a clue to what its function is.

Comment: chip sits between large inductor and electrolytic cap: this is probably a switch-mode power supply IC. It getting hot probably means something else is broken. In effect, you'll need to do more debugging on your own - replacing isn't going to solve this.

Comment: It's most probably a switching regulator from the stuff around it. This chip getting hot can mean a lot of things. It can also mean that there is a lot more broken stuff on that board. It could be in the power supply of your HDD. Try to unplug the HDD (a good idea anyway) and see if it's still getting hot that quickly.
BTW: what do you mean by "does not start"? Any lights? Sounds? Display?

Answer (score 3):

You have a blown part here - looks like a tantalum cap or a diode. Not necessarily the root cause either, but definitely needs replacement.

[image]